# Error 432 while exporting tables from word to excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to export a word doc. tables to an excel file.
Expected result:

1. export only the first row for every column (avoiding the rest of the table content)
2. no space between tables

I tried with this but I get this 432 error on "Set wdDoc = GetObject(wdFileName)":

[432 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcP5g.png)

Can someone help me?

```vb
Sub Trouble()

    Dim word_app As Object, word_doc As Object, word_table As Word.Table, wdFileName As Variant, wdDoc As Object

    Set word_app = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    ActiveSheet.Calculate

    wdFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Word files (*.docx),*.docx", , _
    "Browse for file containing table to be imported")

    If wdFileName = False Then Exit Sub 
    ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").ClearContents

    Set wdDoc = GetObject(wdFileName)
    word_app.Visible = True
    wdDoc.Activate

    excel_row = 1
 
    On Error Resume Next

    For Each word_table In wdDoc.Tables
        Err.Clear
        For i = 1 To word_table.Rows.Count
            
            For j = 1 To word_table.Columns.Count
                part = word_table.Rows(i).Cells(j).Range.Text
                part = Left(part, Len(part) - 1)
                part = Replace(part, vbNewLine, "")
                
                Sheet2.Cells(excel_row, j).Value = part
            Next j
            excel_row = excel_row + 1
        Next i
    Next word_table

    MsgBox "done"

    wdDoc.Save
    'word_app.Quit
    Set wdDoc = Nothing
    Set word_app = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: `Set wdDoc = word_app.Documents.Open(wdFileName)`

Comment: Hi Tim, I followed your suggestion but i get the 424 error message, but i don't understand since the object is assigned . Any clue on which coud be the issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me (just the word-related parts):

```vb
Sub Trouble()

    Dim word_app As Object, wdFileName As Variant, wdDoc As Object

    Set word_app = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    

    wdFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Word files (*.docx),*.docx", , _
                             "Browse for file containing table to be imported")

    If wdFileName = False Then Exit Sub
    
    Set wdDoc = word_app.documents.Open(wdFileName)
    word_app.Visible = True
    wdDoc.Activate
    
End Sub
```